# Search html table

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, search

I have a website that shows a table with data from a database, I'm trying to implement a search feature but can't get it to work.
The code for the search feature is mostly copied from a tutorial I watched, as I'm fairly new to coding. I have tried looking for spelling mistakes, missing brackets, etc, but couldn't get it to work. 
So I'm hoping someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong :)

index.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="description" content="Inventar">
    <meta name="author" content="Martin Eide Bjørndal">
    <title>Ut</title>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/src/css/style.css">
     <!-- jQuery library -->
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Popper JS -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <button class="back" onclick="window.location='../'">
      <img src="/src/icons/back.png">
    </button> <!-- Tilbake knapp -->

    <div class="container-fluid" id="utskjekkcontainer">
      <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-mv-10 bg-light mt-5 rounded p-3">
          <h1 class="text-primary p-2">Utskjekk</h1>
          <hr>
          <div class="form-inline">
            <label for="search" class="font-weight-bold lead text-dark">Søk</label> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <input type="text" name="search" id="search_text" class="form-control form-control-lg rounded-0 border-primary" placeholder="Søk...">
          </div>
          <hr>
          <?php
            include "../src/fn/init.php";
            $stmt=$conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM inventar");
            $stmt->execute();
            $result=$stmt->get_result();
          ?>
          <table class="table table-hover table-light table-striped" id="table_data">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>Navn</th>
                <th>Antall</th>
                <th>Tilgjengelig</th>
                <th>Plassering</th>
                <th>Vekt (kg)</th>
                <th>Størrelse x y z (cm)</th>
                <th>Kommentar</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <?php while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()){ ?>
                <tr>
                  <td><?php echo $row["id"]; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $row["navn"]; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $row["antall"]; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $row["antall_tilgjengelig"]; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $row["plassering"]; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $row["vekt"]; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $row["størrelse"]; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $row["kommentar"]; ?></td>
                </tr>
              <?php } ?>
             </tbody>
           </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#search_text').keyup(function(){
          var search = $(this).val();
          $.ajax({
            url:'action.php',
            method:'post',
            data:{query:search},
            success:function(response){
              $('#table_data').html(response);
            }
          });
        });
      });
    </script>



  </body>

</html>
```

action.php:

```
   <?php

    include "../src/fn/init.php";
    $output = "";

    if(isset($_POST["query"])){
        $search = $_POST["query"];
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM inventar WHERE navn LIKE CONCAT('%','?','%') OR id LIKE CONCAT('%','?','%') OR plassering LIKE CONCAT('%','?','%')");
        $stmt->bind_param("sss",$search, $search, $search);
    } else {
        $stmt=$conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM inventar");
    };
    $stmt->execute();
    $result=$stmt->get_result();

    if($result->num_rows>0){
        $output = "<thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>#</th>
                            <th>Navn</th>
                            <th>Antall</th>
                            <th>Tilgjengelig</th>
                            <th>Plassering</th>
                            <th>Vekt (kg)</th>
                            <th>Størrelse x y z (cm)</th>
                            <th>Kommentar</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>";

        while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()){
            $output .= "
                <tr>
                    <td>".$row["id"]."</td>
                    <td>".$row["navn"]."</td>
                    <td>".$row["antall"]."</td>
                    <td>".$row["antall_tilgjengelig"]."</td>
                    <td>".$row["plassering"]."</td>
                    <td>".$row["vekt"]."</td>
                    <td>".$row["størrelse"]."</td>
                    <td>".$row["kommentar"]."</td>
                </tr>";
        };
        $output .= "</tbody>";
        echo $output;
    } else {
        echo "<h3> Found no match!</h3>";
    };


?>
```

Comment: <td>".echo $row["størrelse".]"</td> your dot is misplaced

Comment: syntax error: in $.ajax function change method="post" to method: "post"

Comment: Thanks!, Now I've fixed those mistakes, it still won't work though.

Comment: I believe the problem to be the $(document).ready(); not being executed, I have no idea why that would be tho.

Comment: Name mismatch: Your table id is named `table_data`, but the Ajax response is using `table-data` ... not the same name reference.

Comment: @PaulT. Thanks! can't believe I didn't spot that, do you see any other mistakes? ive fixed that one and it still won't work.

Comment: Likely have an SQL error (which you have no check). You have 3 `?` placeholders, but are only binding 2?

Comment: @PaulT. That part of the code is directly copied from the tutorial, but I think there is another issue, I tried placing an alert("Hi"); in the keyup function, right before "var search..", when I reloaded the page and started writing in the search field the alert didn't show? is the script not getting executed at all?

Comment: You have another syntax error: the closing `};` to the Ajax success function does not need the `;`  Check your browser console tab AND the server error log to find these sorts of things. Back to the previously mentioned SQL (tutorials are not always 100% correct), have your server log ready, that SQL will likely trigger an error.

Comment: @PaulT. After consulting the browser console, i moved the link to jquerry to the page head, then it all started working!, now however, im getting a parse error on line 34 of action.php, i cant find any mistakes there

Comment: I would remove all the `echo`'s in that area. (appears to be near line 34) Not sure where you found this tutorial, but seems horrendous having all these issues.

Comment: @PaulT.| I've now gotten to the point where the error I'm getting is the binding, how would I go about fixing that?

Comment: Add another `s` to the bind string, and another `$search` variable to the `bind_param` call.

Comment: @PaulT. Thanks! I removed the echos, they were also giving an error! Now I'm getting "number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement"

Comment: I mentioned what to do in my previous comment. (2 things to do, not just 1)

Comment: @PaulT. Yeye I've implemented " $stmt->bind_param("sss",$search, $search, $search);" but im still getting that error.

Comment: What line#, should not be at that point?

Comment: @PaulT. ? what do you mean?

Comment: Unless the query changed, the binding appears to be good (no bind error). The number of variables error should have a line reference? At this point, it would probably be best to update the code in the question with all the latest changes that have been done to this point. May be more obvious.

Comment: The query hasnt changed, the error is on line 9, the same line as  $stmt->bind_param("sss",$search, $search, $search)

Comment: Oh, i think I see ... in the all the `LIKE` clauses, remove the single quotes surrounding the `'?'` to simply look like `?`.

Comment: @PaulT. Thanks! Now it works!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with a large table of data, i stumbled upon [JQuery Datatables](https://datatables.net/)

it has a built in search function, allows sorting and other cool stuff :)

Comment: Looks really cool, I think i might just scrap my own design and use that instead! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can use JQuery Table

```
<script src="js/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script> <script src="js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```

and declare script like this to connect with ur table

```js
`<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#table_data').DataTable();
});
</script>`
```

For more info, u can read this documentation https://datatables.net/